# How to get Token using Twitter API 1.1 in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I am using "**STTwitter**" for getting token from below URL and request body

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/oauth2/token

request body code with URL is below

```
- (void)verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:(void(^)(NSString *username))successBlock errorBlock:(void(^)(NSError *error))errorBlock {

    [self postResource:@"oauth2/token"
         baseURLString:@"https://api.twitter.com"
            parameters:@{ @"grant_type" : @"client_credentials" }
          useBasicAuth:YES
   uploadProgressBlock:nil
 downloadProgressBlock:nil
          successBlock:^(id request, NSDictionary *requestHeaders, NSDictionary *responseHeaders, id json) {

              NSString *tokenType = [json valueForKey:@"token_type"];
              if([tokenType isEqualToString:@"bearer"] == NO) {
                  NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:NSStringFromClass([self class]) code:STTwitterAppOnlyCannotFindBearerTokenInResponse userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : @"Cannot find bearer token in server response"}];
                  errorBlock(error);
                  return;
              }

              self.bearerToken = [json valueForKey:@"access_token"];

              successBlock(_bearerToken);

          } errorBlock:^(id request, NSDictionary *requestHeaders, NSDictionary *responseHeaders, NSError *error) {
              errorBlock(error);


              NSLog(@"ERROR %@",[error description]);

          }];
}
```

For Calling above method i am doing below code

```
STTwitterAppOnly *twitter1 = [[STTwitterAppOnly alloc] init];
    [twitter1 verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:^(NSString *bearerToken) {

        NSLog(@"sd");

        [self.twitter getUserTimelineWithScreenName:@"SEREEN_NAME"
                                  successBlock:^(NSArray *statuses) {

                                      NSLog(@"ERROR ::: %@",[statuses description]);

                                      // ...
                                  } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                                      // ...
                                  }];

    } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        // ...
    }];
```

I got below Error when perform above code...

```
**Error Domain=STHTTPRequest Code=99 "Unable to verify your credentials"**
```

Can you suggest me what I missed in my code?

My concern is that, I want to read twitter feed without login in Twitter.Only using "Consumer Key" and "Secret Key" with Twitter API V1.1.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

if you have ConsumerKey and ConsumerSecret you can try it

```
STTwitterAPIWrapper *twitterAPI = [[STTwitterAPIWrapper twitterAPIApplicationOnlyWithConsumerKey:@"Your Consumer Key" consumerSecret:@"Your Consumer Secret"] autorelease];
[twitterAPI verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:^(NSString *username) {
     [twitterAPI getUserTimelineWithScreenName:@"your ScreenName" count:25 successBlock:^(NSArray *statuses) {
         NSLog(@"Success:%@", statuses);

     } errorBlock:^(NSError *error){
         NSLog(@"Error : %@",error.description);
     }];

} errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"Error : %@",error.description);
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you have enter Consumer key and Consumer Secret in both plist and header prefix...

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted has several issues. First, you're making a request from the verify method error block instead of the success block. Second, you're using the postResource method directly, instead of the higher level one to do what you want.

If all that you want is a bearer token for your consumer tokens, you can just copy / paste the sample code from STTwitter README in the [App Only Authentication](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter#app-only-authentication) section.